# How to find common ngrams between two files?

Tags: python, string, nlp, n-gram

I have two very large text files and I want to find the ngrams that occur in both files. so far all the solutions that I tried find just the common lines. But I'm interested in finding common substrings/ngrams. Is there any efficient way of doing this? I tried the approach of finding all possible ngrams in each line and then comparing them for both files, but it's turning out to be computationally very expensive.